# How do i create a custom scheduler in android?

Tags: android, scheduler

I have a table named `events` whose structure is as follows:

```
id
name
date
time
```

What i want is that at the date and time mentioned in the table a notification should popup on the screen.

I want to understand whether after the application has been installed succeessfully, the procees should always run in the background to check whether the current time has reached the time mentioned in the events table or there is another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you need to make a pending intent and set the time as next whatever predefined time from your table. Now write the Broadcast receiver and in the onRecieve() method apart from doing your other tasks you need the find the next time from your table and set the next pending-intent.